# How to check if all sequence keyword matched in string? - Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of keywords(the number of keywords is depended on user input), I want to check if all keywords are in a sentence with sequence in list.

example of keywords(order of keywords is needed for comparing):

```
keywords = ['Hello', 'my', 'friend']
```

case should return false

```
sentence = ['Dear', 'my', 'friend', 'Hello']
```

case should return true

```
sentence = ['Hello', 'my', 'Dear', 'friend']
```

Here is my code:

```
keywords = ['Hello', 'my', 'friend']
    sentence = ['Dear', 'my', 'friend', 'Hello']
    marker = 0
    for keyword in keywords:
        for word in sentence:
            if keyword == word:
                marker = sentence.index(word) - marker
                if marker < 0:
                    return False
    return True
```

Is there any algorithm I can use to optimize my code? Because once I have duplicated word in sentence it doesn't work

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't think that will work since it will pass the check in the "case should return False" example above. I think they also want to consider ordering of the words, although it may be some other reason I didn't interpret.

Comment: @Shorn Ahh, I missed the ordering requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an iterator from the given sentence, and iterate over the keywords to test if each keyword is found in the sequence generated by the iterator, which follows the order of words in the given sentence:

```
def matches_sequence(keywords, sentence):
    sequence = iter(sentence)
    return all(keyword in sequence for keyword in keywords)
```

so that:

```
keywords = ['Hello', 'my', 'friend']
print(matches_sequence(keywords, ['Dear', 'my', 'friend', 'Hello']))
print(matches_sequence(keywords, ['Hello', 'my', 'Dear', 'friend']))
```

outputs:

```
False
True
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SkinnyClumsyInterchangeability